# Refraction in oil and plastic

Tags: optics, refraction

Can some one help me in understanding this picture. I came across this interesting picture in wikipedia on Refractive index. when green light is refracted in plastic it looks like reddish orange and once it is back to air it is green. Same observation is seen in one of you tube video.
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure, but it can be related to absorption & scattering properties of refracting material

Comment: if it is absorption the all the green light should have absorbed. It is Laser light. if it is scattering then it can not be directional

Comment: How do you know that ? Do you have material absorption spectrum ? There **is** scattering for sure - otherwise you would not see laser beam at all - notice that it travels in direction perpendicular to our view. And because laser light is highly coherent it can only be seen if it beam directly hits into your eye OR if it is scattered by some particles (for example dust, smoke, etc.) on the way. So we only are able to see this picture because of scattering alone. So you are wrong.

Comment: Does the scattering changes the colour?

Comment: BTW, I doubt that it is laser at all, probably NOT. Do you notice at the start of ray path (image left-most side) that light is expanded into many different angles from main ray. This usually happens when rays comes from point-like light source, not a laser. So I'm not first sure if it is a laser or not. Of course if it would be not a laser, then dispersion should be seen in material. But then again, many different factors are unknown here, we just guessing

Comment: can you see this video in you tube. This also shows similar effect but in oil https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wcWf5jHhJl8

Comment: Scattering coefficient depends on ray wavelength, so answer is YES, it can change perceived color. That's why you see blue sky - because of [Rayleigh scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering#Cause_of_the_blue_color_of_the_sky). And even laser is not a strictly 1 wavelength, it usually has **wavelength bandwidth**.

Answer (score 3):

Almost certainly the different color you see along the beam path inside the plastic is due to fluorescence: the green light in the incident beam causes the plastic to fluoresce.  This is a very common effect.  You often can see it in glass, too. Fluorescent light is emitted in all directions, so it can be seen even if there is no scattering.

Comment: Need to add, that actually things are a bit more complicated. Ability to induce fluorescence depends on laser light wavelength. So for _some_ materials green laser light (as shown in tube clip)  may not have enough energy to excite material atoms. But maybe _some_ plastics have low excitation energy levels, so maybe green light wavelength (520–570 nm) is enough. Don't know.